# get-pip.gy version for python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, pip

i want to install PIP on Windows 10 (64). Oddly enough, it's not installed. Now i had download the file and get in the cmd " ERROR: This script does not work on Python 3.6 The minimum supported Python version is 3.7. Please use https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py instead."

... but the version i have tried is from the URL: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.6/get-pip.py Did anyone know where i can find the right one?

Comment: Have you tried using [ensurepip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/#ensurepip)?